# Convert Date and echo for each in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have a list of dates in the format 2012-06-18 which I'm echoing out into an XML file.

```
foreach ($result_array as $date) {
   echo "<market date=\"".$date['saledate']."></market>\n";
}
```

Which works fine.

But when I change my code to display the dates in a different format like so...

```
foreach ($result_array as $date) {
   echo "<market date=\"".date("F j", $date['saledate')]."></market>\n";
}
```

Each date echos out as December 31. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
foreach ($result_array as $date) {
   echo "<market date=\"".date("F j", strtotime($date['saledate']))."></market>\n";
}
```

Your parenthesis were wrongly ordered too.